# cancel a read from an InputStream

Tags: java, inputstream, outputstream

Currently I am using an `ObjecInputStream` to read from a `Socket`, and everything works fine using this simple code:

```
ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
Object response = input.readObject();
```

Now I want to somehow cancel the read, without closing the stream, so that I can later read from it again. Is it possible?

**Edit**: I want to cancel the read just because it is blocking the program flow. I don't need to read the same information twice. I just want to cancel it so that I can send another request and then read the (another) response.

Comment: I get the impression there is more than one way to interpret your question based on the responses so far.

Are you looking to cancel the readObject() [because it's blocking] and be able to call it again later?  Or have the other posters pegged it correctly and you're just looking for a way to roll the stream back (though you'd still have to find a way to break out of the readObject()).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have some kind of "main" thread, then you should perform I/O off of it. Have a thread dedicated to reading and to some extends processing the input. Either queue the results to the main thread if event based, on modify the model if using a shared state design.

Answer (score 2):

See what `ObjectInputStream.markSupported()` returns. If it returns `true`, you can call `ObjectInputStream.mark()` at the beginning and then call `ObjectInputStream.reset()` to rewind the `InputStream` back to the place you marked so you can reuse it later.

Comment: then, what to do if it returns false?
BTW I don't want to read the same data twice, I just want to cancel the read so that I can send another request then read another response.

Comment: @phunehehe: If it returns `false` then mark/reset is not supported by this `InputStream` and this strategy won't work for you. Anyway, if you're not re-reading the same data twice (not mentioned in the original question) then the strategy wouldn't apply anyway. Why don't you simply instantiate a new `ObjectInputStream`? Object instantiation is cheap these days.

Comment: But the program blocks when I make another call to `input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());` I think it must be a problem with the old stream (actually I think they are the same stream from the same socket). Do I have to create another socket?

Comment: @phunehehe: Yeah. Open up a new socket.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [PushBackInputStream](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/PushbackInputStream.html) to accomplish this. After reading some bytes you can unread the bytes.